# JBOSS EAP 6.4 Unable to load topology

Tags: jboss, jboss6.x

in my Jboss web console, the topology view in Domain tab is empty, I don`t know why. Everything is up and running, I just can't see the domain topology in Jboss console. "Unable to load topology"

Comment: Problem solved.

Comment: This is an known issue with IE browser. https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1256637

Comment: Thanks Abhijit Humbe.

Comment: This happens randomly for me (using Chrome). Sometimes it will just refuse to load topology. Then I open it up with Firefox and it loads fine, but I have no idea what causes it. Seems like some cache problem on JBoss.

Answer (score 1):

I just got the "Unable to load topology" error today.

I have separate multinode jboss domain configurations in my env.
one is 6 nodes and one is 3 nodes.  all running 6.4.22.GA

The error came up for me when we were switching ldap user authentication hosts and attempting to do that while leaving the servers up/running as much as possible.

When the domain node was changed to the new ldap server and brought back up we got the topology error.

fix was to bounce jbossas-domain on the other nodes and point to the new ldap server.  After we did that the jboss console was able to display the topology again.

In short my solution was to make sure all the nodes in the jboss domain had the same configuration and then bounce them.